# Looping through text file, finding keywords, creating a dictionary, and then appending dictionary to list of dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, gis

I have this dataset that looks like this:

```
    ['Registration:1005227',
    'FileNumber:A0485456',
    'Status:Terminated',
    'FAA\xa0Study:02-ANE-198-OE',
    'Contact:Department,Regulatory(617)585-7600',
    'Locatedin:\xa0ABINGTON,MALat/Long:42-06-48.0N070-56-58.0W\xa0',
    'PaintingandLightingSpecifications:None',
    'Registration:1015227',
    'FileNumber:A0485451',
     etc etc...]
```

...thousands of times over. Working in pandas, I figured that if I need only the Registration, Lat and Long data, I would loop through each line, detect keywords, and then add a slice to a dictionary.

```
reg = "Registration"
lat = "Lat/"
long = "Long:"

d = {}
theList = []

for line in data:
    if reg in line:
        d["Registration"] = line[13:20]
    if lat in line:
        d["Lat"] = line[-24:-14]   
    if long in line:
        d["Lng"] = line[-13:-2] 

    theList.append(d)
```

In the end, a list of dictionaries would allow me to create a dataframe. The problem that I'm having is that the loop only takes data from the last entry, and adds it to 'theList' [as many times as there are entries.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWjhL.png)

I've tried putting the `.append` outside of the `for` loop. I've tried giving each `if` statement it's own `for` loop, but nothing seems to be working. What am I doing wrong, and is there a better way to approach this problem?

Comment: You're appending multiple references of the one dictionary object. You need to create a new dict for each iteration of your `for` loop.

Comment: This seems too detailed.  Why not simply extract a new data frame from the original, containing only the three columns you need?

Comment: @Prune I tried that at first, the problem with that is the data isn't uniform.

Comment: Your current solution also produces data that is not uniform, in much the same way.  Your dictionaries have missing entries; the resulting data frame would have whatever "missing" imputation you use (such as `NaN`).  I'm not seeing the disconnection ... yet.